# ‘Feel embarrassed or feel embarrassment’

Tags: meaning, grammar, linking-verbs

Which one is right to say?

- He felt embarrassed

Or

- He felt embarrassment

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the first. The verb "feel" can have an adjective complement, and as we are describing someone's feelings, the adjective works well. Compare

> He feels happy.  (Normal)
>
> He feels happiness  (Rare)

The noun form might used rarely, for example:

> John felt something he had not experienced for a long time, embarrassment, even guilt.

Here a noun is required, as it has to be "something..."

Comment: Nice answer, even more your sentence. What does embarrassment act in your sentence, appositive modifier?

Comment: I hadn't thought about it, but, yes appositive I think. You could say "... *namely* embarrassment" with no change in meaning. You could even swap the order "... felt embarrasment, something he had not...."

Comment: How about *Stop exercising if you feel any pain.*? Where pain is a noun word.

Comment: @dan, indeed, as there is no corresponding adjective to "pain".

Comment: @JamesK is *painful* an adjective?

Comment: "Painful" doesn't correspond to "pain" as "happy" does to happiness. Compare "A happy person", with "A painful person". The first is experiencing happiness. The second is causing pain.